# Lots of namespace/assembly reference build errors - Windows Phone 8.1 Client App

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I've just moved to a new computer and re-installed Visual Studio, Azure SDK, and Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. I'm creating a simple HelloWorld Azure Cloud Service client for my simple Service I have written, in order to test everything works. This following program/code worked on my other computer.

This is the code as follows:

```html
namespace HelloCloudClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void button1_Clickyyy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Service1Client svc = new Service1Client();

            svc.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(svc_GetDataCompleted);

            svc.GetDataAsync();
        }

        void svc_GetDataCompleted(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("A network error has occured, please try again!");

                Console.WriteLine("An error occured:" + e.Error);

            }

            textBlock1.Text = e.Result;

        }


    }
}
```

The errors that I am receiving are also as follows. After numerous hours of googling, I can't seem to find a solution. Does anyone know anything that I might be doing wrong? Is there something else I need to configure on my new machine? Thank you!

## [image: Error codes]

Comment: What is your target Framework?

Comment: I've just noticed it doesn't allow me to change target framework under Project > Properties > Application. There are no options regarding framework.

Comment: .NET 4.5 I believe - that's my default option when creating new projects.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Windows Phone application? If yes have you installed Windows Phone SDK when installing Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and also 8.1. The code above mentioned is from a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Project File!

Comment: Do you have any warnings in the Refrences on the Solution Explorer Panel?

Comment: I have one warning in the error list, "The 'configuration' element is not declared" although I looked in my app.config and the <configuration> is there And no, no warnings in the References list.

Comment: Can you share your .csproj?

Comment: Yes, https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=cbe1a1f200cbd972!348&authkey=!ALQoEaPM3at96Wg&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76462/discussion-between-bexolo-and-csharpwinphonexaml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be a External Service linked to localhost which very probably wasn't running on the other machine.
Please link your project to a Service located in a remote location reachable from both computers or run the Service application in each computer you want to test your project.

Comment: It seems that the app works when connecting to a live/hosted service, but not a local host.

Comment: that's because you must run the service project on each computer you want to test your Windows Phone Project